# Error on running sample

Tags: openscenegraph

I downloaded the source code of openscenegraph and build it using cmake and vc++ 2013. And then I failed to run sample when I set argument like that:

```
set path=%path%;D:\workspaces\OpenSceneGraph\build\bin
D:\workspaces\OpenSceneGraph\runexamples.bat
```

the error messages showed like this:

```
C:\Users\sw>D:\workspaces\OpenSceneGraph\runexamples.bat

C:\Users\sw>echo osgversion
osgversion

C:\Users\sw>osgversion
OpenSceneGraph Library 3.5.1


C:\Users\sw>echo osgunittests
osgunittests

C:\Users\sw>osgunittests matrix
'osgunittests' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\sw>osgunittests qt
'osgunittests' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
......
```

it said that 'osgunittests', 'osgunittests', 'osganimate' etc. are not recognized. I think I was failed on building the source code. But How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

osgUnitTest is an application belonging to the osg examples.
Most likely you have built osg without examples, there is a related option in the main cmake file [here](https://github.com/openscenegraph/OpenSceneGraph/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L701)